# ImageButton creates 404 error for YouTube link

Tags: asp.net

I have this link to [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/agla4me): It works fine when you type or copy it to the URL box.

when I embed it in my code, it works with the anchor tag, but not with the `asp ImageButton`.

This code works:

```
<a href ="http://www.youtube.com/agla4me" ><img src="Images/youtube.png"  style= "border: none"/></a>
```

This code does not work.  It will give you 404:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ibYouTube" runat="server" ImageUrl ="Images/youtube.png" PostBackUrl="http://www.youtube.com/agla4me"  />
```

I ran fiddler and looked at the request header, I saw ImageButton have pragma: no-cache.
Does no-cache cause 404 error because youtube caches? If so, how do I turn off no-cache for Imagebutton.

Thanks

Comment: Mr. @MsBugKiller, why don't you try and accept some of the answers people have provided to your 5 questions so far? It will encourage people to continue helping you.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the source that is getting generated with the `ImageButton` control. My thought is that you are misunderstanding the way that `PostBackUrl` works. The PostBack is different from a `Redirect` (which is what I assume that you are trying to do). To do this using an `asp:ImageButton` you can have it Redirect `onClientClick` using javascript like this:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ibYouTube" runat="server" ImageUrl ="Images/youtube.png" OnClientClick="location.href='http://www.youtube.com/agla4me'" runat="server" />
```

I suspect that youtube probably gets confused when you attempt to Post data to it. To better understand PostBacks, check out [W3schools Postback introduction here](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_button_postbackurl.asp)

It is probably easier to just use a regular anchor tag though. Unless you have something more special in mind. Also, make sure to include `runat="server"` in any ASP control on your page.